# Convert date in format accepted by restService

Tags: angular, date-format

I need to convert a date into a date accepted by a restService.
I receive a date `2016-06-26` from a form and I want to convert it to call restService.

The restService accepts the format  `2016-06-13T00:00:00+0200`.

I tried all format proposed by `Date` in javascript (`toUTCString()`, `toJson`, ...) but nothing works.

Comment: You can dig directly into DatePipe formats here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ae75e3640a2d9eb1e897a0771d92b976c5a42c75/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts

Comment: I use ngmodel (<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="startDateWork)  and i think that pipes does not work with ngmodel

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs

`moment.utc([yyyy, mm, dd]).format();`

please refer `http://momentjs.com/docs/`

Comment: Sorry but i cannot use moment